# having trouble replacing text in a div in jquery

Tags: jquery, scope

This should be very simple. I've done it many times. But for some reason, I'm having trouble over writing the text that's in a div.

The div is hardcoded in the html, but I refer to the div from an `on("click")` call inside a function. Maybe this is a scope problem?

```js
var objPlayerdata; //object array of arrays of players straight from database
var objUnpicked = {}; //array of array of players available to be picked
getPlayers();

function getPlayers() { //initial download of player data

    objUnpicked = [{"PlayerID":"1","Num":"57","First":"Montravius","Last":"Adams","Suffix":"","Position":"DL","Photo":"adams-montravius","Height":"6-4","Weight":"304","College":"Auburn","Experience":"7","Summary":"Nose tackle played 26% of the defensive snaps."},{"PlayerID":"71","Num":"74","First":"Spencer","Last":"Anderson","Suffix":"","Position":"OL","Photo":"anderson-spencer","Height":"6-5","Weight":"305","College":"Maryland","Experience":"R","Summary":"Second 7th-rounder has flexibility to play G or T."},{"PlayerID":"20","Num":"19","First":"Calvin","Last":"Austin","Suffix":"III","Position":"WR","Photo":"austin-calvin-iii","Height":"5-9","Weight":"162","College":"Memphis","Experience":"2","Summary":"Has speed to be running\/receiving\/return threat."},{"PlayerID":"38","Num":"35","First":"Luq","Last":"Barcoo","Suffix":"","Position":"CB","Photo":"barcoo-luq","Height":"6-1","Weight":"180","College":"San Diego State","Experience":"2","Summary":"Lanky XFL All-Star but a long shot to make it."},{"PlayerID":"88","Num":"95","First":"Keeanu","Last":"Benton","Suffix":"","Position":"DL","Photo":"benton-keeanu","Height":"6-4","Weight":"309","College":"Wisconsin","Experience":"R","Summary":"Could play right away, or watch and learn for now."},{"PlayerID":"12","Num":"9","First":"Chris","Last":"Boswell","Suffix":"","Position":"Special","Photo":"boswell-chris","Height":"6-2","Weight":"185","College":"Rice","Experience":"9","Summary":"Had a down year while dealing with groin injury."},{"PlayerID":"15","Num":"13","First":"Miles","Last":"Boykin","Suffix":"","Position":"WR","Photo":"boykin-miles","Height":"6-4","Weight":"220","College":"Notre Dame","Experience":"5","Summary":"Special teams coverage could keep him around."},{"PlayerID":"79","Num":"84","First":"Ja'Marcus","Last":"Bradley","Suffix":"","Position":"WR","Photo":"bradley-jaMarcus","Height":"6-0","Weight":"198","College":"La.-Lafayette","Experience":"2","Summary":"Former Brown J.B. will try to look like A.B. in camp."},{"PlayerID":"22","Num":"21","First":"Hakeem","Last":"Butler","Suffix":"","Position":"WR","Photo":"butler-hakeem","Height":"6-5","Weight":"227","College":"Iowa State","Experience":"2","Summary":"Huge wideout rekindled his NFL chances in XFL."},{"PlayerID":"18","Num":"16","First":"Jordan","Last":"Byrd","Suffix":"","Position":"WR","Photo":"byrd-jordan","Height":"5-9","Weight":"170","College":"San Diego State","Experience":"R","Summary":"KR\/PR hopes to make some Byrd calls this summer."},{"PlayerID":"80","Num":"85","First":"Dan","Last":"Chisena","Suffix":"","Position":"WR","Photo":"chisena-dan","Height":"6-3","Weight":"203","College":"Penn State","Experience":"3","Summary":"Unless he's a gunner, he's not making the team."},{"PlayerID":"64","Num":"67","First":"Le'Raven","Last":"Clark","Suffix":"","Position":"OL","Photo":"clark-leRaven","Height":"6-5","Weight":"311","College":"Texas Tech","Experience":"8","Summary":"Journeyman is insurance policy for the 20-somethings."},{"PlayerID":"59","Num":"61","First":"Mason","Last":"Cole","Suffix":"","Position":"OL","Photo":"cole-mason","Height":"6-5","Weight":"298","College":"Michigan","Experience":"6","Summary":"Played hurt but didn't miss a game as starting C."},{"PlayerID":"58","Num":"60","First":"Dylan","Last":"Cook","Suffix":"","Position":"OL","Photo":"cook-dylan","Height":"6-6","Weight":"305","College":"Montana","Experience":"1","Summary":"Project who converted from QB in college (yes, really)."},{"PlayerID":"74","Num":"78","First":"James","Last":"Daniels","Suffix":"","Position":"OL","Photo":"daniels-james","Height":"6-4","Weight":"327","College":"Iowa","Experience":"6","Summary":"Young veteran didn't miss a snap at RG in first year here."},{"PlayerID":"36","Num":"33","First":"Duke","Last":"Dawson","Suffix":"","Position":"DB","Photo":"dawson-duke","Height":"5-10","Weight":"198","College":"Florida","Experience":"4","Summary":"On practice squad in '22; competing at slot corner."},{"PlayerID":"67","Num":"69","First":"Kevin","Last":"Dotson","Suffix":"","Position":"OL","Photo":"dotson-kevin","Height":"6-4","Weight":"321","College":"La.-Lafayette","Experience":"3","Summary":"Committed 12 penalties in first full season; now a backup."},{"PlayerID":"65","Num":"68","First":"William ","Last":"Dunkle","Suffix":"","Position":"OL","Photo":"dunkle-william","Height":"6-5","Weight":"330","College":"San Diego State","Experience":"1","Summary":"Heavy hands but lack of athleticism is his weakness."},{"PlayerID":"89","Num":"96","First":"Breiden","Last":"Fehoko","Suffix":"","Position":"DL","Photo":"fehoko-breiden","Height":"6-3","Weight":"300","College":"LSU","Experience":"3","Summary":"On his to-do list: Stop the run, stop the run, stop the run."},{"PlayerID":"42","Num":"39","First":"Minkah","Last":"Fitzpatrick","Suffix":"","Position":"S","Photo":"fitzpatrick-minkah","Height":"6-1","Weight":"207","College":"Alabama","Experience":"6","Summary":"Reigning team MVP is among the league's best."},{"PlayerID":"77","Num":"82","First":"Dez","Last":"Fitzpatrick","Suffix":"","Position":"WR","Photo":"fitzpatrick-dez","Height":"6-2","Weight":"208","College":"Louisville","Experience":"2","Summary":"Sleeper pick to have a productive camp\/preseason."},{"PlayerID":"82","Num":"88","First":"Pat","Last":"Freiermuth","Suffix":"","Position":"TE","Photo":"freiermuth-pat","Height":"6-5","Weight":"258","College":"Penn State","Experience":"3","Summary":"Here's a play call for Matt Canada: 3rd-and-Muth."},{"PlayerID":"76","Num":"81","First":"Zach","Last":"Gentry","Suffix":"","Position":"TE","Photo":"gentry-zach","Height":"6-8","Weight":"265","College":"Michigan","Experience":"5","Summary":"Can be a bridge to Washington on a one-year deal."},{"PlayerID":"55","Num":"54","First":"Markus","Last":"Golden","Suffix":"","Position":"LB","Photo":"golden-markus","Height":"6-2","Weight":"260","College":"Missouri","Experience":"9","Summary":"Brings 47 career sacks to No. 3 pass rush role."},{"PlayerID":"31","Num":"29","First":"Alfonzo","Last":"Graham","Suffix":"","Position":"RB","Photo":"graham-alfonzo","Height":"5-9","Weight":"180","College":"Morgan State","Experience":"R","Summary":"Undersized UDFA signed after rookie camp tryout."},{"PlayerID":"54","Num":"53","First":"Kendrick","Last":"Green","Suffix":"","Position":"OL","Photo":"green-kendrick","Height":"6-4","Weight":"315","College":"Illinois","Experience":"3","Summary":"Working at C again but hanging by a thread."},{"PlayerID":"27","Num":"25","First":"Darius","Last":"Hagans","Suffix":"","Position":"RB","Photo":"hagans-darius","Height":"6-0","Weight":"210","College":"Virginia State","Experience":"R","Summary":"Averaged 5.4 yards per carry in '22 in Division II."},{"PlayerID":"40","Num":"38","First":"Madre","Last":"Harper","Suffix":"","Position":"CB","Photo":"harper-madre","Height":"6-1","Weight":"196","College":"Southern Illinois","Experience":"2","Summary":"Brings NFL experience to bottom of the roster."},{"PlayerID":"24","Num":"22","First":"Najee","Last":"Harris","Suffix":"","Position":"RB","Photo":"harris-najee","Height":"6-2","Weight":"230","College":"Alabama","Experience":"3","Summary":"Durable in back-to-back 1,000-yard seasons."},{"PlayerID":"10","Num":"6","First":"Pressley","Last":"Harvin","Suffix":"III","Position":"Special","Photo":"harvin-pressley-iii","Height":"6-0","Weight":"255","College":"Georgia Tech","Experience":"3","Summary":"Must hold off NFL-caliber competition in Year 3."},{"PlayerID":"53","Num":"51","First":"Nick","Last":"Herbig","Suffix":"","Position":"LB","Photo":"herbig-nick","Height":"6-2","Weight":"240","College":"Wisconsin","Experience":"R","Summary":"Posted 20 sacks, 30 TFLs as sophomore and junior."},{"PlayerID":"68","Num":"71","First":"Nate","Last":"Herbig","Suffix":"","Position":"OL","Photo":"herbig-nate","Height":"6-4","Weight":"334","College":"Stanford","Experience":"5","Summary":"Can he also be backup C? (49 career snaps there.)"},{"PlayerID":"78","Num":"83","First":"Connor","Last":"Heyward","Suffix":"","Position":"TE","Photo":"heyward-connor","Height":"6-0","Weight":"230","College":"Michigan State","Experience":"2","Summary":"Offensive chess piece has chemistry with No. 8."},{"PlayerID":"90","Num":"97","First":"Cam","Last":"Heyward","Suffix":"","Position":"DL","Photo":"heyward-cameron","Height":"6-5","Weight":"295","College":"Ohio State","Experience":"13","Summary":"Just 2.5 sacks away from all-time franchise record."},{"PlayerID":"57","Num":"56","First":"Alex","Last":"Highsmith","Suffix":"","Position":"LB","Photo":"highsmith-alex","Height":"6-4","Weight":"242","College":"Charlotte","Experience":"4","Summary":"Breakout campaign led to lucrative new contract."},{"PlayerID":"56","Num":"55","First":"Cole","Last":"Holcomb","Suffix":"","Position":"LB","Photo":"holcomb-cole","Height":"6-1","Weight":"240","College":"North Carolina","Experience":"5","Summary":"Signed to be every-down presence in middle of field."},{"PlayerID":"41","Num":"38","First":"Jason","Last":"Huntley","Suffix":"","Position":"RB","Photo":"huntley-jason","Height":"5-9","Weight":"195","College":"New Mexico State","Experience":"2","Summary":"Practice squad holdover is small but quick."},{"PlayerID":"19","Num":"18","First":"Diontae","Last":"Johnson","Suffix":"","Position":"WR","Photo":"johnson-diontae","Height":"5-10","Weight":"183","College":"Toledo","Experience":"5","Summary":"Had 16 1st-down catches on 3rd-down, but no TDs."},{"PlayerID":"69","Num":"72","First":"Manny","Last":"Jones","Suffix":"","Position":"DL","Photo":"jones-manny","Height":"6-4","Weight":"290","College":"Colorado State","Experience":"1","Summary":"One of many D-linemen, and way down the line."},{"PlayerID":"73","Num":"77","First":"Broderick","Last":"Jones","Suffix":"","Position":"OL","Photo":"jones-broderick","Height":"6-5","Weight":"311","College":"Georgia","Experience":"R","Summary":"Left tackle of the future; maybe the present, too."},{"PlayerID":"25","Num":"23","First":"Damontae","Last":"Kazee","Suffix":"","Position":"S","Photo":"kazee-damontae","Height":"5-11","Weight":"174","College":"San Diego State","Experience":"7","Summary":"Couple INTs in 9 games helped get him re-signed."},{"PlayerID":"30","Num":"28","First":"Miles","Last":"Killebrew","Suffix":"","Position":"S","Photo":"killebrew-miles","Height":"6-2","Weight":"222","College":"Southern Utah","Experience":"8","Summary":"Back again as cerebral special teams captain."},{"PlayerID":"49","Num":"46","First":"Christian","Last":"Kuntz","Suffix":"","Position":"Special","Photo":"kuntz-christian","Height":"6-1","Weight":"227","College":"Duquesne","Experience":"3","Summary":"Local guy living the dream as a reliable snapper."},{"PlayerID":"2","Num":"--","First":"Nick","Last":"Kwiatkoski","Suffix":"","Position":"LB","Photo":"kwiatkoski-nick","Height":"6-2","Weight":"242","College":"West Virginia","Experience":"8","Summary":"Experienced Bethel Park grad signed after minicamp tryout."},{"PlayerID":"91","Num":"98","First":"DeMarvin","Last":"Leal","Suffix":"","Position":"DL","Photo":"leal-deMarvin","Height":"6-4","Weight":"290","College":"Texas A&M","Experience":"2","Summary":"Still looking for first NFL sack after missing 6 games."},{"PlayerID":"86","Num":"92","First":"Isaiahh","Last":"Loudermilk","Suffix":"","Position":"DL","Photo":"loudermilk-isaiahh","Height":"6-7","Weight":"293","College":"Wisconsin","Experience":"3","Summary":"Started 3 games, then barely played after Week 9."},{"PlayerID":"8","Num":"4","First":"Braden","Last":"Mann","Suffix":"","Position":"Special","Photo":"mann-braden","Height":"5-11 ","Weight":"198","College":"Texas A&M","Experience":"4","Summary":"Jets punter the last 3 years; won Ray Guy Award in '18."},{"PlayerID":"85","Num":"91","First":"Jonathan","Last":"Marshall","Suffix":"","Position":"DL","Photo":"marshall-jonathan","Height":"6-3","Weight":"310","College":"Arkansas","Experience":"2","Summary":"Thickest DL on roster but it's a deep unit."},{"PlayerID":"60","Num":"62","First":"Ryan","Last":"McCollum","Suffix":"","Position":"OL","Photo":"mccollum-ryan","Height":"6-5","Weight":"300","College":"Texas A&M","Experience":"2","Summary":"Only path to roster is to win backup C job."},{"PlayerID":"28","Num":"26","First":"Anthony","Last":"McFarland","Suffix":"Jr.","Position":"RB","Photo":"mcFarland-anthony-jr","Height":"5-8","Weight":"193","College":"Maryland","Experience":"3","Summary":"Vying to be RB3 now that Benny Snell is gone."},{"PlayerID":"62","Num":"65","First":"Dan","Last":"Moore","Suffix":"Jr.","Position":"OL","Photo":"moore-dan-jr","Height":"6-5","Weight":"315","College":"Texas A&M","Experience":"3","Summary":"Has started 34 of possible 35 games so far at LT."},{"PlayerID":"9","Num":"5","First":"Tanner","Last":"Morgan","Suffix":"","Position":"QB","Photo":"morgan-tanner","Height":"6-2","Weight":"215 ","College":"Minnesota","Experience":"R","Summary":"Up-and-down 5-year starter in Big Ten went undrafted."},{"PlayerID":"47","Num":"44","First":"Tanner","Last":"Muse","Suffix":"","Position":"LB","Photo":"muse-tanner","Height":"6-2","Weight":"227","College":"Clemson","Experience":"4","Summary":"Mainly here for special teams like the old No. 44."},{"PlayerID":"48","Num":"45","First":"Toby","Last":"Ndukwe","Suffix":"","Position":"LB","Photo":"ndukwe-toby","Height":"6-3","Weight":"250","College":"Sam Houston State","Experience":"R","Summary":"Odds are slightly higher than Sam Houston himself."},{"PlayerID":"35","Num":"31","First":"Keanu","Last":"Neal","Suffix":"","Position":"S","Photo":"neal-keanu","Height":"6-0","Weight":"211","College":"Florida","Experience":"8","Summary":"Strong safety allowed 3 TDs last year with Bucs."},{"PlayerID":"23","Num":"21","First":"Tre","Last":"Norwood","Suffix":"","Position":"S","Photo":"norwood-tre","Height":"6-0","Weight":"194","College":"Oklahoma","Experience":"3","Summary":"Firmly established as Minkah Fitzpatrick's backup."},{"PlayerID":"63","Num":"66","First":"James","Last":"Nyamwaya","Suffix":"","Position":"DL","Photo":"nyamwaya-james","Height":"6-5","Weight":"305","College":"Merrimack","Experience":"R","Summary":"UDFA came long way from Division III ranks, but ... "},{"PlayerID":"92","Num":"99","First":"Larry","Last":"Ogunjobi","Suffix":"","Position":"DL","Photo":"ogunjobi-larry","Height":"6-3","Weight":"305","College":"Charlotte","Experience":"7","Summary":"Got 3 years, $28.75 million but it's back-loaded."},{"PlayerID":"72","Num":"76","First":"Chukwuma","Last":"Okorafor","Suffix":"","Position":"OL","Photo":"okorafor-chukwuma","Height":"6-6","Weight":"320","College":"W. Michigan","Experience":"6","Summary":"PFF grade (61.2) was lowest among team's OL."},{"PlayerID":"83","Num":"89","First":"Gunner","Last":"Olszewski","Suffix":"","Position":"WR","Photo":"olszewski-gunner","Height":"6-0","Weight":"190","College":"Bemidji State","Experience":"5","Summary":"Just 6.9 yards\/punt return before getting benched."},{"PlayerID":"43","Num":"40","First":"David","Last":"Perales","Suffix":"","Position":"LB","Photo":"perales-david","Height":"6-3","Weight":"255","College":"Fresno State","Experience":"R","Summary":"UDFA rushes hard but has an uphill climb."},{"PlayerID":"21","Num":"20","First":"Patrick","Last":"Peterson","Suffix":"","Position":"CB","Photo":"peterson-patrick","Height":"6-1","Weight":"203","College":"LSU","Experience":"13","Summary":"Just turned 33 -- and coming off 5 INTs for Vikings."},{"PlayerID":"16","Num":"14","First":"George","Last":"Pickens","Suffix":"","Position":"WR","Photo":"pickens-george","Height":"6-3","Weight":"200","College":"Georgia","Experience":"2","Summary":"Only 52 catches as a rookie but 25 of 20+ yards"},{"PlayerID":"11","Num":"8","First":"Kenny","Last":"Pickett","Suffix":"","Position":"QB","Photo":"pickett-kenny","Height":"6-3","Weight":"220","College":"Pitt","Experience":"2","Summary":"Tossed 5 TDs to just 1 INT over final 8 games."},{"PlayerID":"46","Num":"42 ","First":"James","Last":"Pierre","Suffix":"","Position":"CB","Photo":"pierre-james","Height":"6-2","Weight":"185","College":"Fla. Atlantic","Experience":"4","Summary":"Job in jeopardy as young studs join his group."},{"PlayerID":"26","Num":"24","First":"Joey","Last":"Porter","Suffix":"Jr.","Position":"CB","Photo":"porter-joey-jr","Height":"6-2","Weight":"193","College":"Penn State","Experience":"R","Summary":"No INTs but 11 pass breakups last season."},{"PlayerID":"44","Num":"40","First":"Monte","Last":"Pottebaum","Suffix":"","Position":"RB","Photo":"pottebaum-monte","Height":"6-1","Weight":"244","College":"Iowa","Experience":"R","Summary":"Mullet + wants to hit people = folk hero fullback."},{"PlayerID":"5","Num":"3","First":"B.T.","Last":"Potter","Suffix":"","Position":"Special","Photo":"potter-bt","Height":"5-10 ","Weight":"200","College":"Clemson","Experience":"R","Summary":"Made 75.3% of FGs and all but one XP in college."},{"PlayerID":"39","Num":"37","First":"Elijah","Last":"Riley","Suffix":"","Position":"S","Photo":"riley-elijah","Height":"6-0","Weight":"205","College":"Army","Experience":"3","Summary":"Versatile backup safety and inside corner."},{"PlayerID":"52","Num":"50","First":"Elandon","Last":"Roberts","Suffix":"","Position":"LB","Photo":"roberts-elandon","Height":"6-1","Weight":"238","College":"Houston","Experience":"8","Summary":"Career-best 107 tackles for Dolphins in '22."},{"PlayerID":"14","Num":"11","First":"Allen","Last":"Robinson","Suffix":"II","Position":"WR","Photo":"robinson-allen-ii","Height":"6-2","Weight":"220","College":"Penn State","Experience":"10","Summary":"Caught 33 passes for 339 yards and 3 TDs in '22."},{"PlayerID":"45","Num":"41","First":"Kenny","Last":"Robinson","Suffix":"","Position":"S","Photo":"robinson-kenny","Height":"6-2","Weight":"200","College":"West Virginia","Experience":"3","Summary":"Wilkinsburg native aiming to revive his career at home."},{"PlayerID":"87","Num":"93","First":"Mark","Last":"Robinson","Suffix":"","Position":"LB","Photo":"robinson-mark","Height":"5-11","Weight":"235","College":"Mississippi","Experience":"2","Summary":"Explosive athlete but needs to learn the position."},{"PlayerID":"50","Num":"48","First":"Quincy","Last":"Roche","Suffix":"","Position":"LB","Photo":"roche-quincy","Height":"6-3","Weight":"245","College":"Miami","Experience":"2","Summary":"6th-rounder in '21 circles back for Round 2."},{"PlayerID":"4","Num":"2","First":"Mason","Last":"Rudolph","Suffix":"","Position":"QB","Photo":"rudolph-mason","Height":"6-5 ","Weight":"235","College":"Oklahoma State","Experience":"6","Summary":"Didn't see a snap last regular season as No. 3 QB."},{"PlayerID":"51","Num":"49","First":"Chapelle","Last":"Russell","Suffix":"","Position":"LB","Photo":"russell-chapelle","Height":"6-1","Weight":"230","College":"Temple","Experience":"3","Summary":"Added to practice squad last year after roster cuts."},{"PlayerID":"70","Num":"73","First":"Isaac","Last":"Seumalo","Suffix":"","Position":"OL","Photo":"seumalo-isaac","Height":"6-4","Weight":"303","College":"Oregon State","Experience":"8","Summary":"Technician who brings Eagles experience to LG job."},{"PlayerID":"37","Num":"34","First":"Chandon","Last":"Sullivan","Suffix":"","Position":"CB","Photo":"sullivan-chandon","Height":"5-11","Weight":"189","College":"Georgia State","Experience":"6","Summary":"Nickel had career-high 60 stops last year for Vikings."},{"PlayerID":"3","Num":"--","First":"Rex","Last":"Sunahara","Suffix":"","Position":"Special","Photo":"sunahara-rex","Height":"6-6 ","Weight":"242 ","College":"West Virginia","Experience":"1","Summary":"Will try to unseat incumbent snapper Christian Kuntz."},{"PlayerID":"29","Num":"27","First":"Cory","Last":"Trice","Suffix":"Jr.","Position":"CB","Photo":"trice-cory-jr","Height":"6-3","Weight":"206","College":"Purdue","Experience":"R","Summary":"7th-rounder with size eager to add CB depth."},{"PlayerID":"13","Num":"10","First":"Mitch","Last":"Trubisky","Suffix":"","Position":"QB","Photo":"trubisky-mitch","Height":"6-2","Weight":"220","College":"North Carolina","Experience":"7","Summary":"Signed new deal to be Pickett's long-term backup."},{"PlayerID":"32","Num":"29","First":"Levi","Last":"Wallace","Suffix":"","Position":"CB","Photo":"wallace-levi","Height":"6-0","Weight":"179","College":"Alabama","Experience":"6","Summary":"Opportunistic, settled in as starter down stretch."},{"PlayerID":"33","Num":"30","First":"Jaylen","Last":"Warren","Suffix":"","Position":"RB","Photo":"warren-jaylen","Height":"5-8","Weight":"215","College":"Oklahoma State","Experience":"2","Summary":"Proved worth as capable rusher, receiver, blocker."},{"PlayerID":"75","Num":"80","First":"Darnell","Last":"Washington","Suffix":"","Position":"TE","Photo":"washington-darnell","Height":"6-7","Weight":"264","College":"Georgia","Experience":"R","Summary":"Loves to block and an intriguing red-zone target."},{"PlayerID":"84","Num":"90","First":"T.J.","Last":"Watt","Suffix":"","Position":"LB","Photo":"watt-tj","Height":"6-4","Weight":"252","College":"Wisconsin","Experience":"7","Summary":"Elite when healthy, so he's due for a bounce-back."},{"PlayerID":"66","Num":"68","First":"Armon","Last":"Watts","Suffix":"","Position":"DL","Photo":"watts-armon","Height":"6-5","Weight":"307","College":"Arkansas","Experience":"5","Summary":"Started Weeks 4-16 in only season with Bears."},{"PlayerID":"17","Num":"15","First":"Cody","Last":"White","Suffix":"","Position":"WR","Photo":"white-cody","Height":"6-3","Weight":"215","College":"Michigan State","Experience":"2","Summary":"Has been on practice squad or roster since '20."},{"PlayerID":"34","Num":"30","First":"Chris","Last":"Wilcox","Suffix":"","Position":"CB","Photo":"wilcox-chris","Height":"6-2","Weight":"195","College":"BYU","Experience":"1","Summary":"Depth piece was 7th-round pick of Bucs in '21."},{"PlayerID":"61","Num":"64","First":"Jarrid","Last":"Williams","Suffix":"","Position":"OL","Photo":"williams-jarrid","Height":"6-6","Weight":"308","College":"Miami","Experience":"1","Summary":"Camp body at tackle who was undrafted in '22."},{"PlayerID":"81","Num":"87","First":"Rodney","Last":"Williams","Suffix":"","Position":"TE","Photo":"williams-rodney","Height":"6-4","Weight":"235","College":"Tennessee-Martin","Experience":"1","Summary":"Athletic ex-WR but has been glued to practice squad."}];
    getPosition("ALL");

}

function getPosition(thisPosition) {

    //reflect instructions for each position
      $('.instructions').empty();
      switch(thisPosition) {
        case 'QB':
        $('.instructions').html('Pick a maximum of 3 QBs.');
        break;
        case 'RB':
        $('.instructions').html('Pick a maximum of 5 RBs.');
        break;
        case 'WR':
        $('.instructions').html('Pick a maximum of 7 WRs.');
        break;
         case 'TE':
        $('.instructions').html('Pick a maximum of 4 TEs.');
        break;
        case 'OL':
        $('.instructions').html('Pick a maximum of 9 OLs.');
        break;
         case 'DL':
        $('.instructions').html('Pick a maximum of 9 DLs.');
        break;
         case 'LB':
        $('.instructions').html('Pick a maximum of 8 LBs.');
        break;
        case 'CB':
        $('.instructions').html('Pick a maximum of 7 CBs.');
        break;
        case 'S':
        $('.instructions').html('Pick a maximum of 5 Ss.');
        break;
        case 'Special':
        $('.instructions').html('Pick a maximum of 3 special team members.');
        break;
        case 'ALL':
        $('.instructions').html('');
        break;
        default:
        // code block
      }

     $('.players').empty(); //get rid of any former players showing on the web page
    var appendString = ""; //initialize string of html of player data

    //look through unpicked players object and return those that match clicked position
    for (var i = 0; i< objUnpicked.length; i++) { //go through the object of unpicked players
      if (thisPosition == "ALL") { //if they want to display all players, display them all
        appendString += "<div class='player'>\n"
               + "<div class='headshot'><img src='img/" + objUnpicked[i].Photo + ".png'/></div>\n"
               + "<div class='stats'>\n"
               + "<div class='name'><span class='number'>" + objUnpicked[i].Num + "</span> <span class='first'>" + objUnpicked[i].First + "</span> <span class='last'>" + objUnpicked[i].Last + "</span><span class='suffix'> " + objUnpicked[i].Suffix + "</span> <span class='position'>- " + objUnpicked[i].Position + "</span></div>\n"
               + "<div class='resume'>College: <span class='college'>" + objUnpicked[i].College + "</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;Yrs. Exp.: <span class='years-experience'>" + objUnpicked[i].Experience + "</span></div>\n"
               + "<div class='physical'><span class='height'>" + objUnpicked[i].Height + "</span> <span class='weight'>" + objUnpicked[i].Weight + "</div>\n"
               + "<div class='summary'>" + objUnpicked[i].Summary + "</div>\n"
               + "</div>\n"
               + "<button class='draft' value='" + objUnpicked[i].PlayerID + "'>DRAFT</button>\n"
               + "</div>\n"; 
      }
      else {
        if (objUnpicked[i].Position == thisPosition) { //otherwise, if they want to see only players of a certain position, only display players with the clicked-on position
          appendString += "<div class='player'>\n"
                 + "<div class='headshot'><img src='img/" + objUnpicked[i].Photo + ".png'/></div>\n"
                 + "<div class='stats'>\n"
                 + "<div class='name'><span class='number'>" + objUnpicked[i].Num + "</span> <span class='first'>" + objUnpicked[i].First + "</span> <span class='last'>" + objUnpicked[i].Last + "</span><span class='suffix'> " + objUnpicked[i].Suffix + "</span> <span class='position'>- " + objUnpicked[i].Position + "</span></div>\n"
                 + "<div class='resume'>College: <span class='college'>" + objUnpicked[i].College + "</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;Yrs Exp: <span class='years-experience'>" + objUnpicked[i].Experience + "</span></div>\n"
                 + "<div class='physical'><span class='height'>" + objUnpicked[i].Height + "</span> <span class='weight'>" + objUnpicked[i].Weight + "</div>\n"
                 + "<div class='summary'>" + objUnpicked[i].Summary + "</div>\n"
                 + "</div>\n"
                 + "<button class='draft' value='" + objUnpicked[i].PlayerID + "'>DRAFT</button>\n"
                 + "</div>\n"; 


        }
      }
    }
    $('.players').append(appendString); //fill in the players div

     $('.draft').on("click", function() { //if click the draft button associated with each player
      alert('clicked draft'); //this works
      var thisGuysPosition = "";

      var thisPlayer = $(this).attr("value"); //get the ID of the clicked player

      //find this player's position in the array
      for (var j = 0; j< objUnpicked.length; j++) {
        if (objUnpicked[j].PlayerID == thisPlayer) {
          thisGuysPosition = objUnpicked[j].Position;
        }
      }
      alert(thisGuysPosition); //this works
      var clickedIndex;
      var countQB = 0; //we haven't picked anybody yet, so counts are 0
      var countWR = 0; var countRB = 0; var countTE = 0; var countOL = 0; var countDL = 0; var countLB = 0; var countCB = 0; var countS = 0; var countSpecial = 0;

      if (thisGuysPosition == "QB") {
        alert('counting now'); //this works
        countQB++; 
        var QBleft = 3-countQB;
        alert($('.instructions').html()); //this works
                //the following two statements only work the first time 
                //they don't update on subsequent times. Why?
        $('.numLeft').text("");
        $('.numLeft').text("You have " + QBleft + " QBs left."); 
      }
     }); //end click draft button 
} //end getPosition function
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="instructions" id="instructions"></div>
<div class="numLeft"></div>

<div class="players">
<!-- fills in with results of query -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your code example so that it can be run within your question and the problem can be reproduced. That's quite a long script with ajax calls that can't be reproduced here. Just include the relevant code that reproduces the problem without all the extras.

Comment: @Chris Barr - It's hard to do that with a database call. Do you have a recommendation for how to reproduce that?

Comment: Just use some mock data, don't actually call anything remotely. Since we don't know what kind of data that returns anyway, that will help out too since the problem could be in there.  Just remove the ajax call and hard code the value of `objPlayerdata`.  Put all your code into a snippet in your question using the button that looks like this: `[<>]`

Comment: @ChrisBarr: OK, I've replaced the dB call with the data.

Comment: I've just edited your question so that it is now a snippet that can be run inside the question. It currently has a syntax error probably due to the `jQuery.parseJSON(playerdata)` line since it's now already using JSON data. I didn't want to actually edit your code so please go and fix that.  When your edit the question scroll down below the snippet buttons and click the "edit the above snippet" link to bring up the snippet editor. You can run your code inside of that to make sure it works and reproduces the problem you are describing.

Comment: @ChrisBarr I made that change. But now the question is all code and you don't see the .instructions or .numLeft divs.

Comment: I would like to know what would you need to see instead of what you see currently. That may help clarify what the issue is.

Comment: @LajosArpad When you click the draft button, if the person's position is QB, the .numLeft element should update telling you how many quarterbacks you have left

Comment: So if I click on the DRAFT of "60 Dylan Cook - OL", then something needs to be change. Can you tell me visually what I would need to see then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine and it updates the text just fine.  Your issue was tha tyou have `var countQB = 0;` defined inside the click event of the `draft` button.  Each time you click it you reset the count back to zero.  You just need to define that outside of the click event so you can keep track of that number between clicks.

The next time you write a question PLEASE only include a *minimal* amount of code that can reproduce the issue. Your question was a huge block of code, with too much sample data.

See my below edits.  I removed a ton of sample data as that is not needed to reproduce the issue at hand. I also defined some new variables for selecting elements so that you don't have to keep selecting them over and over again

```js
//Select some elements to be re-used
var $instructions = $('.instructions')
var $players = $('.players');
var $numLeft = $('.numLeft');

//application state
var countQB = 0;

//Sample data
var objUnpicked = [
  {PlayerID: "1",Num: "57",First: "Montravius",Last: "Adams",Suffix: "",Position: "DL",Photo: "adams-montravius",Height: "6-4",Weight: "304",College: "Auburn",Experience: "7",Summary: "Nose tackle played 26% of the defensive snaps.",},
  {PlayerID: "9",Num: "5",First: "Tanner",Last: "Morgan",Suffix: "",Position: "QB",Photo: "morgan-tanner",Height: "6-2",Weight: "215 ",College: "Minnesota",Experience: "R",Summary: "Up-and-down 5-year starter in Big Ten went undrafted.",},
  {PlayerID: "11",Num: "8",First: "Kenny",Last: "Pickett",Suffix: "",Position: "QB",Photo: "pickett-kenny",Height: "6-3",Weight: "220",College: "Pitt",Experience: "2",Summary: "Tossed 5 TDs to just 1 INT over final 8 games.",},
  {PlayerID: "46",Num: "42 ",First: "James",Last: "Pierre",Suffix: "",Position: "CB",Photo: "pierre-james",Height: "6-2",Weight: "185",College: "Fla. Atlantic",Experience: "4",Summary: "Job in jeopardy as young studs join his group.",},
];
getPosition("ALL");

function getPosition(thisPosition) {
    //reflect instructions for each position
    $instructions.empty();
    switch(thisPosition) {
      case 'QB':
        $instructions.html('Pick a maximum of 3 QBs.');
        break;
      case 'RB':
        $instructions.html('Pick a maximum of 5 RBs.');
        break;
      case 'WR':
        $instructions.html('Pick a maximum of 7 WRs.');
        break;
      case 'TE':
        $instructions.html('Pick a maximum of 4 TEs.');
        break;
      case 'OL':
        $instructions.html('Pick a maximum of 9 OLs.');
        break;
      case 'DL':
        $instructions.html('Pick a maximum of 9 DLs.');
        break;
      case 'LB':
        $instructions.html('Pick a maximum of 8 LBs.');
        break;
      case 'CB':
        $instructions.html('Pick a maximum of 7 CBs.');
        break;
      case 'S':
        $instructions.html('Pick a maximum of 5 Ss.');
        break;
      case 'Special':
        $instructions.html('Pick a maximum of 3 special team members.');
        break;
      case 'ALL':
        $instructions.html('');
        break;
      default:
      // code block
    }

    $players.empty(); //get rid of any former players showing on the web page
    var appendString = ""; //initialize string of html of player data

    //look through unpicked players object and return those that match clicked position
    for (var i = 0; i< objUnpicked.length; i++) { //go through the object of unpicked players
      var pick = objUnpicked[i];
      if (thisPosition == "ALL") { //if they want to display all players, display them all
        appendString += "<div class='player'>\n"
               + "<div class='headshot'><img src='img/" + pick.Photo + ".png'/></div>\n"
               + "<div class='stats'>\n"
               + "<div class='name'><span class='number'>" + pick.Num + "</span> <span class='first'>" + pick.First + "</span> <span class='last'>" + pick.Last + "</span><span class='suffix'> " + pick.Suffix + "</span> <span class='position'>- " + pick.Position + "</span></div>\n"
               + "<div class='resume'>College: <span class='college'>" + pick.College + "</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;Yrs. Exp.: <span class='years-experience'>" + pick.Experience + "</span></div>\n"
               + "<div class='physical'><span class='height'>" + pick.Height + "</span> <span class='weight'>" + pick.Weight + "</div>\n"
               + "<div class='summary'>" + pick.Summary + "</div>\n"
               + "</div>\n"
               + "<button class='draft' value='" + pick.PlayerID + "'>DRAFT</button>\n"
               + "</div>\n"; 
      } else {
        if (pick.Position == thisPosition) { //otherwise, if they want to see only players of a certain position, only display players with the clicked-on position
          appendString += "<div class='player'>\n"
                 + "<div class='headshot'><img src='img/" + pick.Photo + ".png'/></div>\n"
                 + "<div class='stats'>\n"
                 + "<div class='name'><span class='number'>" + pick.Num + "</span> <span class='first'>" + pick.First + "</span> <span class='last'>" + pick.Last + "</span><span class='suffix'> " + pick.Suffix + "</span> <span class='position'>- " + pick.Position + "</span></div>\n"
                 + "<div class='resume'>College: <span class='college'>" + pick.College + "</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;Yrs Exp: <span class='years-experience'>" + pick.Experience + "</span></div>\n"
                 + "<div class='physical'><span class='height'>" + pick.Height + "</span> <span class='weight'>" + pick.Weight + "</div>\n"
                 + "<div class='summary'>" + pick.Summary + "</div>\n"
                 + "</div>\n"
                 + "<button class='draft' value='" + pick.PlayerID + "'>DRAFT</button>\n"
                 + "</div>\n"; 
        }
      }
    }
    $players.html(appendString); //fill in the players div

    $('.draft').on("click", function() { //if click the draft button associated with each player
      var thisGuysPosition = "";
      var thisPlayer = $(this).attr("value"); //get the ID of the clicked player

      //find this player's position in the array
      for (var j = 0; j< objUnpicked.length; j++) {
        if (objUnpicked[j].PlayerID == thisPlayer) {
          thisGuysPosition = objUnpicked[j].Position;
        }
      }

      if (thisGuysPosition == "QB") {
        countQB++; 
        var QBleft = 3-countQB;
        console.log('counting QBs', countQB, QBleft);
        $numLeft.text("You have " + QBleft + " QBs left."); 
      }
    }); //end click draft button 
} //end getPosition function
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="instructions" id="instructions"></div>
<div class="numLeft"></div>

<hr>

<div class="players">
<!-- fills in with results of query -->
</div>
```